# Add a string to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that returns an  multidimensional `array()` I want to concatenate a string to every value of that array. How can I do this

for example my string:

```
$this->$string = 'helloAddMeToArray';
```

and my array is:

```
array(array('url' => 'PleaseAddAStringToMeIAmLonely'));
```

So i need my array value to be like this: helloAddMeToArrayPleaseAddAStringToMeIAmLonely

I tried concatenating these with '.' but does not allow me

Comment: Unrelated: *multidementional* is an awesome Freudian typo

Comment: hehe silly auto correct on chrome 'multidimensional' xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$oldArray = array(array('url' => 'PleaseAddAStringToMeIAmLonely'));
$newArray = array();
$this->string = 'helloAddMeToArray';

foreach($oldArray as $o) {
 $newArray[] = array('url' => $this->string . $o['url']);
}
```

Comment: Note the difference in the '$this->$string = 'helloAddMeToArray';' on this too. $this->$string is incorrect. @Mave has quite rightly changed it to $this->string = 'helloAddMeToArray';

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
First get string from your multidimentional Array, and type cast it.

```
$myString2 = (string)$myArray[0]->url;
```

Now use concatination:    `$string.$myString2;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array could look like :

```
[
    "key"=>[
           "keyK"=>"val"
            ],
     "key2"=>"val2"
]
```

and you want to concatenate a string to every value from that array you should use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function .
This is a short snnipet doing this job :

```
$stringToConcatenate=$this->$string = 'helloAddMeToArray';
$callback($val,$key) use ($stringToConcatenate){
$val.=$val.$stringToConcatenate;
}
array_walk_recursive($youArray,$callback);
```

I hope it helps you .